# Find unique subset

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query 4 columns A, B, C and D to find records where there is more than 1 D per A/B.

Relationship is hierarchical from A to D; there can be multiple Ds per C, multiple Cs per B etc.

e.g. here I want to find record 2 from column A because columns A and B are the same but C and D is different

```
A   B   C   D
-------------
1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1
1   1   3   1
2   1   1   1
2   1   2   2
```

I figured to group on all 4 & use a `having` count d > 1 but this oddly returns no results when there should be many.

Is there any way to do this without using a whole bunch of sub-queries, or is that the only way?

NB: data is not numerical the above is just an example. Actual data is string type.

Comment: *find records where there is more than 1 D per A/B* is not the same as *I want to find record 2 from column A because columns A and B are the same but C and D is different*. Is C of any importance in this requirement?

Comment: @Mithrandir I was referring to col A, there are two subsets in the table 1 & 2

Comment: @forpas Actually I guess not, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by a, b and set the condition in the having clause:

```
select a, b
from tablename
group by a, b
having count(distinct d) > 1
```

If you want all the rows and columns of the table that meet your conditions:

```
select t.*
from tablename t 
inner join (
    select a, b
    from tablename
    group by a, b
    having count(distinct d) > 1
) d on d.a = t.a and d.b = t.b
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select a
from t
group by a
having min(d) <> max(d);
```

Or if you want both `c` and `d` to be taken into account:

```
having min(c) <> max(c) and min(d) <> max(d);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have explained data is not numerical, that was just for example, they are strings

Comment: @Absinthe . . . Numerical data has nothing to do with this answer.  I'm not sure what you are trying to say in your comment.  Often, `max()` and `min()` have better performance than `count(distinct)`.

Comment: I assumed min and max only worked on numerical data but having tried your query it does work. Can you expand on why min and max work with non-numeric data?

Comment: @Absinthe . . . Your assumption is wrong.  `min()` and `max()` work on almost every data type.  I would also point out that this answer is not only correct but was several minute earlier than the other answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I robbed you of some points...? Appreciate the answer but maybe you could have put more detail as to why it works.